# Go-routines with channels not running parallely

Tags: go, parallel-processing, goroutine

```
package main
import "time"
func main() {
    stringCh := make(chan func() (string))
    go func() {
        stringCh <- func() (string) {
            return stringReturner()
        }
        close(stringCh)
    }()

    intCh := make(chan func() (int))
    go func() {
        intCh <- func() (int) {
            return intReturner()
        }
        close(intCh)
    }()

    str := (<-stringCh)()
    print("Printing str: ", str,"\n\n")
    num := (<-intCh)()
    print("Printing int: ", num,"\n\n")     
}

func intReturner()int{
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    print("Inside int returner\n\n");
    return 1;
}

func stringReturner()string{
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    print("Inside string returner\n\n");
    return "abcd";
}
```

Output:

Inside string returner

Printing str: abcd

**WAIT OF 5 SECONDS**

Inside int returner

Printing int: 1

https://play.golang.org/p/oE2ybs7Jo-W

Why is this coding taking 10 seconds to execute instead of 5? We are parallelizing the calls by spawning two go-routines right (1 for string returner and 1 for int returner), but why is the int returner executing after the string returner executes?

Comment: While the answers below are technically correct, the key insight is the difference between "reading a func value from a chan of func" and "executing the func". Usually the concurrent code is structured in such a way that goroutines directly write values to the chan (not funcs that generate a value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The channel is returning function with sleep, and such function got called in sequential manner. That is why it will take 10s in general.

https://play.golang.org/p/UpHD7Ttw03R

Comment: Oh I see, so you mean to say that the since when we are reading from the channel, we execute sleep in each of the functions, it takes 5+5 seconds?

Comment: yes, as the underlying functions got called sequentially, but not part of goroutine. I move sleep function call in goroutine in the above playground.

Comment: why is that though? Is there a reason for this? because I was thinking, sleep should happen parallely for both, only after which they return the values to the respective channels. (And this should ideally happen parallely too)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/VV-fFUza52W
I have removed the sleep, and we still see the for loops executing sequentially here.

Comment: sleep should happen in parallel if the intReturner and stringReturner are called in parallel. In the original snippet, (<-stringCh)() and (<-intCh)() are called sequentially by main goroutine.

Comment: How does the ordering of how we fetch values from the channel matter? Shouldn't the go-routines be pushing values to the channels parallely anyways? 
So is the solution for parallelism to be achieved, is to read from the channels with go-routines as well?

Comment: In the original snippet and your new snippet, (<-stringCh)() and (<-intCh)() are still called sequentially by main goroutine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234242/discussion-between-swastik-udupa-and-sayboras).

Comment: Channels don't inherently grant parallelism. `go` grants parallelism. You're sending in parallel but reading sequentially and synchronously. Your better bet is to use buffered channels to achieve a non-blocking write, and then read from each channel in its own go routine.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are only writing to the channels parallelly. But the read from the channels are happening one-after-the-other. To fix this, you can read from both channels from separate go routines

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(2)
go func() {
  defer wg.Done()
  str := (<-stringCh)()
  print("Printing str: ", str, "\n\n")
}()
go func() {
  defer wg.Done()
  num := (<-intCh)()
  print("Printing int: ", num, "\n\n")
}()
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: How does the ordering of read matter? I agree that they are happening sequentially, but shouldnt they be just reading the results of the functions that were executed by the go-routines? Since these functions happened parallelly i.e the sleep for 5 seconds by both also should have happened parallelly right?

Comment: The first 2 go routines are not actually calling the functions. They are just enqueuing the functions to the channels. The actual "calling" of the function happens when you do `(<-stringCh)()` and `(<-intCh)()`. Thats when the sleep happens. And these sleeps happen sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions moving the sleep method into go routine to run both functions concurrently in 5s:

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    stringCh := make(chan func() string)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        stringCh <- func() string {
            return stringReturner()
        }
        close(stringCh)
    }()

    intCh := make(chan func() int)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        intCh <- func() int {
            return intReturner()
        }
        close(intCh)
    }()

    str := (<-stringCh)()
    print("Printing str: ", str, "\n\n")
    num := (<-intCh)()
    print("Printing int: ", num, "\n\n")
}

func intReturner() int {
    print("Inside int returner\n\n")
    return 1
}

func stringReturner() string {
    print("Inside string returner\n\n")
    return "abcd"
}
```

Output:

```
Inside string returner

Printing str: abcd

Inside int returner

Printing int: 1
```